# Access get value from previous record

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access query with the following

```
GL_A.Account, 
GL_P.FiscalYear, 
GL_P.FiscalPeriod, 
GL_P.BeginningBalance, 
GL_P.DebitAmount, 
GL_P.CreditAmount, 
[BeginningBalance]+([DebitAmount]-[CreditAmount]) AS EndingBalance
```

The problem is that `BeginningBalance` only has values for January (FiscalPeriod 1).

I need to have a new field `ActualBeginngBal` which comes from the previous month `EndingBalance` (Except January)

[image]

Note: there are many account #'s but each account only has 1 record per FiscalPeriod/FiscalYear

Your help would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: Are `Account`, `FiscalYear` and `FiscalPeriod` stored as text in the database?  Just wondering as  your screenshot shows them left aligned and `FiscalPeriod` has a leading 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps.  Put a 2nd copy of the table in the query, joined to the 1st copy on Account and FiscalYear but not on FiscalPeriod.  Then the ActualBeginningBalance can be calculated from the 2nd copy of the table with a constraint to select only FiscalPeriod < the FiscalPeriod from the 1st table.  Note - you may get a null results for January, which you may need to convert to a 0.

OK, it's a bit more complicated - I did end up using a subquery similar to the other response, but calculated the EB instead of trying to pull it from the table

```
SELECT Ledger.Account, Ledger.FiscalYear, Ledger.FiscalPeriod, 
[BeginningBalance]+
       IIf([FiscalPeriod]<>"01",
             (select sum(T.BeginningBalance+T.DebitAmount-T.CreditAmount) 
             from Ledger T 
              where T.account=Ledger.account and T.FiscalYear=Ledger.FiscalYear and T.FiscalPeriod<Ledger.FiscalPeriod)
        ,0) 
       AS ActualBeginningBalance, 
Ledger.DebitAmount AS DebitAmount, 
Ledger.CreditAmount AS CreditAmount, 
[ActualBeginningBalance]+[DebitAmount]-[CreditAmount] AS EndingBalance
FROM Ledger;
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but FiscalPeriod 01 should get values from FiscalPeriod 12 of the previous FiscalYear so the join wouldn't work there.

Comment: It looks like Period 1 has a BB in the data - you might be able to use something for ActualBB like BB (from the 1st table) + sum(BB+Debits-Credits) from the 2nd table with period<period(from 1st table).  January will get the prior year from the 1st table and add nothing from the 2nd table (here's where you need to convert null to 0).  Feb thru Dec will get the prior year from the 2nd table, as well as the prior month credits & debits for the current year.

Comment: "The join won't wont there" - you may need to use a left join instead of inner join top make sure to get data for period 1

Comment: just curious - did this help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i would need SQL to try it, i cannot figure out how to get from the previous record

Comment: Thank you, Thank you... it is a bit slow, but workable, thanks again

Comment: If it's unacceptably slow, it might improve performance to calculate the EB in a separate query, then join the 2 queries.  Let me know if that's necessary - it's not a big step from this solution to that one. It's especially easy if you only need each month's EB and not the ActualBB shown in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL does the job and returns the table below (with my test data):
[image]

```
SELECT    T1.Account
        , T1.FiscalYear
        , T1.FiscalPeriod
        , T1.ActualBeginngBal
        , (
           SELECT TOP 1 T2.EndingBalance
           FROM   Table1 T2
           WHERE CLNG(T2.FiscalYear & Format(T2.FiscalPeriod,"00")) <
                 CLNG(T1.FiscalYear & Format(T1.FiscalPeriod,"00")) AND
                 T2.Account = T1.Account
           ORDER BY CLNG(T2.FiscalYear & Format(T2.FiscalPeriod,"00")) DESC
           ) AS BeginningBalance
        , T1.EndingBalance
FROM    Table1 T1
```

Comment: comment deleted

Comment: Ah, good point.  I got so stuck into working it out that I forgot that bit.

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks for the reply, but I was not able to get it going.. FYI the original table only has these fields. GL_P.AccountKey, GL_P.FiscalYear, GL_P.FiscalPeriod, GL_P.BeginningBalance, GL_P.DebitAmount, GL_P.CreditAmount

Answer (score 0):

IT WOULD BE BETTER IF YOU USE BeginningBalance in primary table. Because it is only one record belong to one account. it is one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving to the previous record, grabbing the value, and returning to the original record.

For example:

```vb
Private Sub txtXYZ1_AfterUpdate()

    Dim tmpXYZ As Single
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
    tmpXYZ = txtXYZ1
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
    txtPriorXYZ = tmpXYZ
    txtXYZChange = txtXYZ1 - txtPriorXYZ

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the Access Recordset is not necessarily sorted in the correct order (meaning by Fiscal Year an Period). Access often returns records according to its own logic and not even in the order they were entered! So it may return the correct results but not with total certainty. Also, what do you do if you are not moving from record to record?