# Calculating field duration of different records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a calculated field in an Access DB however am having trouble working out how to best do it.
The field is “Duration” which needs to be the difference between two “SecsLapsed” values. These values all are assigned an “order” which is the sequence of the data/observed events ie 1, 2, 3, 4, etc..

Order one will always be Secslapsed = 0 (as it is the beginning of the record)
Following records need to calculate duration from the difference between secslapsed values for example for Order2, duration = Secslapsed(for orde3) – Secslapsed (for order2). The order value in the equation however must be relative to the order record ie. Order10 will calculate difference between secslapsed for order11 – secslapsed for order10.
Any ideas?

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access get value from previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629523/access-get-value-from-previous-record)

Answer (score 0):

Given a table `Table1` with your mentioned numeric field `Duration` this would be your query:

```
Select
  Duration,
  Duration - Nz(
    (Select Top 1 Duration From Table1 As Sub Where Sub.Duration < Table1.Duration Order By duration Desc)
    ,0) As SecsLapsed
From Table1
```

If there also is a field like `Project` in your table to separate such 'duration packages', you could use this:

```
Select
  Project, Duration,
  Duration - Nz(
    (Select Top 1 Duration From Table1 As Sub Where Sub.Project = Table1.Project And Sub.Duration < Table1.Duration Order By duration Desc)
    ,0) As SecsLapsed
From Table1
Order By Project, Duration
```