# Sql: How to get previous row/day close quote?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've a "classic" sql table for Stock Quotes:

Date, Ticker, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume

I want to calculate % change of day, so i need to get Previous day Close and Today Close.

How can I do efficently  in standard Sql ?

EDIT: my data example. Change value have to be calculated getting previous day close.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please tag the data base you are using and also provide sample data and expected result

Comment: I'm using Ms Access but in future i'd like to migrate to MySql/MariaDb

Comment: Please provide your sample data and expected result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access get value from previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629523/access-get-value-from-previous-record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any reasonable database you would simply use `lag()`.  Oh well, that precludes MS Access.  You can do this with a correlated subquery.  The following gets the previous close:

```
select q.*,
       (select top (1) q2.close
        from quotes as q2
        where q2.ticker = q.ticker and q2.quotedate < q.quotedate
        order by q2.quotedate desc
       ) as prev_close
from quotes as q;
```

I'm not sure exactly how you are calculating the change, but you can use a subquery:

```
select q.*,
       (close - prev_close) / prev_close as change_ratio
from (select q.*,
             (select top (1) q2.close
              from quotes as q2
              where q2.ticker = q.ticker and q2.quotedate < q.quotedate
              order by q2.quotedate desc
             ) as prev_close
      from quotes as q
     ) as q;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sel ticker,quotedate,open,high,low,close,
100.00*(abs(close-lag(close) over(order by quotedate)))/lag(close) over(order by quotedate) as change 
from table
```

This would be a typical SQL way using lag