# Is there a way to do this using an SQL query in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Basically, I want to know how many days an employee is an active subordinate for a given supervisor on a given month.

The sample data comes from a single table with a few columns:

```
EmployeeName    Previous_Supervisor Updated_Supervisor  Updated_Status  ChangeType  EffectiveDate
john    peter   james       Supervisor  16-Sep-20
john    james   jude        Supervisor  24-Sep-20
john    jude    jude    Resigned    Status  30-Sep-20

All columns are just short text, except for EffectiveDate
```

And here's what I want to achieve through a query (ActiveDayCount column):

```
EmployeeName    Previous_Supervisor Updated_Supervisor  Updated_Status  ChangeType  EffectiveDate   ActiveDayCount
john    peter   james       Supervisor  16-Sep-20   15
john    james   jude        Supervisor  24-Sep-20   8
john    jude    jude    Resigned    Status  30-Sep-20   6
```

ActiveDayCount column:

```
First row's ActiveDayCount is 15 since the effective date is Sep 16, 2020, so that counted Sept 1-15.
This means for 15 days, john was Peter's(Previous_Supervisor) subordinate.
    Second row's ActiveDayCount is 8 since the effective date is Sep 24, 2020, so that counted Sept 16-23.
This means for 8 days, john was james'(Previous_Supervisor) subordinate.
    Third row's ActiveDayCount is 6 since the effective date is Sep 30, 2020, so that counted Sept 24-29.
This means for 6 days, john was jude's(Previous_Supervisor) subordinate before he resigned.
```

EDIT:
Here's a simple query I have to get the first table:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Previous_Supervisor, Updated_Supervisor, Updated_Status, ChangeType, EffectiveDate
FROM RosterHistory
```

Can this be done in MS access using SQL queries?

Comment: Please share with us the SQL you would like to use, and tell us where it is failing in ms-access.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my post. It's just a straightforward query. I'm trying to start from scratch to get the desired output.

Comment: Your question is missing some vital information, such as the full structure of the involved tables and sample data. Check out the suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info  (I'm certain what you are after can be done in MS Access).

Comment: @user9601310 Edited my question. The sample data comes from just 1 table. Contains a few Text and 1 date columns.

Comment: So you need value from previous record to calculate elapsed days. Does this answer your question? [Access get value from previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629523/access-get-value-from-previous-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this gives something close to what you've asked for. (Whether it's what you **want** or **need** may be a different matter as there are assumptions built into your question, such as that all your dates fall within a given month and hence if there is no prior record then the days are counted from the beginning of the month).

```
SELECT EmployeeName, 
       Previous_Supervisor, 
       Updated_Supervisor, 
       ChangeType, 
       Updated_Status, 
       EffectiveDate, 
       (SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate) FROM RosterHistory AS rh
             WHERE EmployeeName = RosterHistory.EmployeeName 
             AND EffectiveDate < RosterHistory.EffectiveDate) AS DatePrevious, 
        IIF(ISNULL(DatePrevious),
            DAY(EffectiveDate) - 1, 
            EffectiveDate - DatePrevious) AS ActiveDayCount
FROM RosterHistory;
```

Note: Although it looks innocuous, the **"AS rh"** in `RosterHistory AS rh` above is critically important. Without that the query will run but will give incorrect output/no values for the DatePrevious column.

Just to note, I have tested this in MS Access 2016 with a copy of the sample data provided.