# Is there a way to calculate the difference between a list of dates in MS Access?

Tags: date, ms-access, intervals

Here is an example of an entry for one client:

| Client Name | Call Date |
| --- | --- |
| A Williams | 4/14/22 |
| A Williams | 5/13/22 |
| A Williams | 6/14/22 |
| A Williams | 7/6/22 |

Is there a way to do a calculation in MS Access that will show me the difference between each instance and the previous call? The goal would be to have something like shown below, because ultimately I want to be able to show the average # of days between this client's calls.

| Client Name | Call Date | Time B/w Calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A Williams | 4/14/22 | N/A |
| A Williams | 5/13/22 | 29 |
| A Williams | 6/14/22 | 31 |
| A Williams | 7/6/22 | 22 |

Thank you all in advance for your help/guidance.

DateDiff does not work for the specific type of calculation I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access get value from previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629523/access-get-value-from-previous-record). Also review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Answer (score 1):

Use a *subquery* with `Top 1`

```sql
SELECT 
    [Client Calls].[Client Name], 
    [Client Calls].[Call Date], 
    DateDiff("d",
        (Select Top 1 T.[Call Date] 
        From [Client Calls] As T 
        Where 
            T.[Client Name] = [Client Calls].[Client Name] And 
            T.[Call Date] < [Client Calls].[Call Date] 
        Order By 
        [Call Date] Desc), 
        [Call Date]) AS [Time B/w Calls]
FROM 
    [Client Calls]
ORDER By
    [Client Calls].[Client Name], 
    [Client Calls].[Call Date];
```

Output:

| Client Name | Call Date | Time B/w Calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A Williams | 2022-04-14 |  |
| A Williams | 2022-05-13 | 29 |
| A Williams | 2022-06-14 | 32 |
| A Williams | 2022-07-06 | 22 |

Comment: I will give this a try and follow up, thank you!

Comment: I must have made a mistake bc I keep getting a syntax error when I try to run the query.  

(SELECT 
SuperUsers.Name,
SuperUsers.Incident Number,
SuperUsers.Incident Date and Time
DateDiff(“d”,
  (Select Top 1 T.[Incident Date and Time]
From SuperUsers As T
Where
 T.Name = SuperUsers.Name And
 T.Incident Number = SuperUsers.Incident Number And
 T.Incident Date and Time < SuperUsers.Incident Date and Time
Order By
Incident Date and Time Desc),
Incident Date and Time) AS Time Between Calls
FROM
 SuperUsers
ORDER By
 SuperUsers.Name,
 SuperUsers.Incident Date and Time;)

Comment: I realized I didn't use the brackets, going to edit and try again - I thought they were sort of like "fill in the blank" indicators.

Comment: Added brackets, still no luck.  I appreciate all your help though, I'm obviously way out of my depth here.

Comment: It's tested and verified here. So copy-paste to the SQL pane of a new query and it will run.